# Rows column in Query Plan confusing

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a MySql query

```
 SELECT TE.company_id, 
        SUM(TE.debit- TE.credit) As summation 
 FROM Transactions T JOIN Transaction_E TE2 
      ON (T.parent_id = TE2.transaction_id) 
 JOIN Transaction_E TE 
      ON (TE.transaction_id = T.id AND TE.company_id IS NOT NULL) 
 JOIN Accounts A 
      ON (TE2.account_id=A.id AND A.deactivated_timestamp=0) 
 WHERE (TE.company_id IN (1,2)) 
   AND A.user_id=2341 GROUP BY TE.company_id;
```

When I explain the query, the plan for it is like (in summary):

```
 | Select type | table | type | rows |
 -------------------------------------
 | SIMPLE      | A     | ref  | 2    |
 | SIMPLE      | TE2   | ref  | 17   |
 | SIMPLE      | T     | ref  | 1    |
 | SIMPLE      | TE    | ref  | 1    |
```

But if I do a count(*) on the same query (instead of SUM(..) ), then it shows that there are ~40k rows for a particular company_id. What I don't understand is why the query plan shows so few rows being scanned while there is at least 40k rows being processed. What does the rows column in the query plan represent? Does it not represent the number of rows that get processed in that table? In that case it should be at most 2*17*1*1 = 34 rows?

Answer (score 0):

The query plan just shows a high level judgement on the expected number of rows required per table to meet the end result.
It is to be used as a tool for judging as to how the optimizer is 'seeing' your query, and to help it a bit, in case query performance is worse or can be improved.

There is always a possibility that the query plan is built based on an earlier snapshot of statistics, and hence should not be taken on face value, especially while dealing with cardinality.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but there is still a huge different between what it suggests (~34 rows) and what it ends up doing (40k rows). How does it come up with those numbers? those numbers look random to me now

Answer (score 0):

Well, first let's get rid of the computational bug:

```
SELECT  TE.company_id, TE.summation
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  company_id,
                SUM(debit - credit) As summation
            FROM Transaction_E
            WHERE  company_id IN (1,2)
      ) TE
    JOIN Transactions T    ON TE.transaction_id = T.id
    JOIN Transaction_E TE2 ON T.parent_id = TE2.transaction_id
    JOIN Accounts A        ON TE2.account_id = A.id
      AND  A.deactivated_timestamp = 0
    WHERE  A.user_id = 2341;
```

Your query is probably summing up the same company multiple times before doing the `GROUP BY`.  My variant avoids that inflation of the aggregate.

I got rid of `TE.company_id IS NOT NULL` because it was redundant.

See what the `EXPLAIN` says about this, then let's discuss your question about `EXPLAIN` further.

Comment: I tried the query you suggested. There are two problems: first, the result is not the same and second, the query plan has one more row of DERIVED select type and it scans ~40k row for that derived select

Comment: I felt the subquery was required to get the correct values for the SUM.  Does it?